# How to update document in sqlite database & phone storage in Android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am building an App in Android using web services. What I am trying to do is Synchronization function. I am getting some properties from web server and I have one boolean value into it, if Boolean is true then it will update my downloaded document.

But I am stuck over here either I need to first delete the document and then replace it or I can directly replace the document. Code is like this:

```
SoapObject DocResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();    
        Log.i("Uspdated Documentss", DocResponse.toString());   
        for(int i=0; i < DocResponse.getPropertyCount(); i++)
        {
            SoapObject SingleSubFolder = (SoapObject)DocResponse.getProperty(i);        
            ID = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(0).toString();
            fileLongName = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(1).toString();
            UserFileName = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(2).toString();
            url = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(3).toString();
            fileExtension = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(4).toString();
            lastModifiedDate = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(5).toString();
            SubjectType = SingleSubFolder.getProperty(6).toString();
            IsUpdated = SingleSubFolder.hasProperty("IsUpdated");
            db = new DMS_Database(context);
            if(IsUpdated==true)
            {

 // How to perform replace function from database here???
 // Is there any need of download manager so that again it download new folder into the phone storage or into the database???

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setTitle(UserFileName);
            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
                {
                    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                }
                    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/Downloads", UserFileName);
                    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)Activtyclass.mAct.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                    manager.enqueue(request);
            }
            db.close();
        }
}   
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, " Network Exception : " + e
                + "Please check network connectivity.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Database:this is my database method...Is it right???

```
public void update_Doc(String Id, String name, String url)
{
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues updatenote = new ContentValues();
updatenote.put(DOCUMENT_ID, Id);
updatenote.put(DOCUMENT_NAME, name);
updatenote.put(DOCUMENT_URL, url);
db.update(DOCUMENT_TABLE, updatenote, DOCUMENT_ID + "=?" , new String[]    {String.valueOf(Id)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void update_Doc(String Id, String name, String url)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues updatenote = new ContentValues();
    updatenote.put(DOCUMENT_ID, Id);
    updatenote.put(DOCUMENT_NAME, name);
    updatenote.put(DOCUMENT_URL, url);
    long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(DOCUMENT_TABLE, null, updatenote,  SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
    if (id == -1) 
    {
        db.update(DOCUMENT_TABLE, updatenote, DOCUMENT_ID + "=?" , new String[]    {String.valueOf(Id)});
    }

}
```

Comment: But how to implement this method in Activity?

Comment: You implement it in your database class and just call update_Doc in your activity

Comment: okay, is there any need to use download manager in the activity?db = new DMS_Database(context);
    if(IsUpdated==true)
    {
     db.update_Doc(ID, UserFileName, url);

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean. You are the one who know if there is a need to download or not. Either that or you do not express your idea clearly.

Comment: I want to say this is synchronization method and I am using Broadcast Receiver, i want to run this method in back end so that automatically after 15 mints document replaced with new one...

Comment: What is your sequence? Server send some doc and your broadcast receiver receive it and you insert or update the database. What happen if it is an insert? what do you want to do next? If it is an update what do you want to do next?

Comment: If doc's are updated then downloaded document also replace in local phone storage, I want replacement also in local phone storage, Is it possible?

Comment: What happen when insert instead of update? what do you replace in local storage? the same document?

Comment: yes, the same document if there is any updated version on the server.Because I am getting these documents from the server using web services.

Comment: Insert perform download method but this is synchronization purpose, means if document new version available it will replace old with new automatically when I will call synch method for that i have used shared preferences.

Comment: If you want to save in local storage I do not see any problem, If you save the document with file name document1 if document1 already exists then it will be overwritten.

Comment: Yes exactly, that is fine, I have done with the same. Problem is when i need to update the document

Comment: Isn't it when the server send the document it is a newer one?

Comment: yes.. right..I want If client has downloaded the document before it was updated then synch perform at back end and document get updated automatically. is it possible???

Comment: You have to put the date and compare then it is possible. It is 3:30 AM here and I am going to sleep. If you still need some help tomorrow leave me a note.